# Redirected to another URL error when trying to upload file using ckanclient

Tags: ckan

I am trying to upload a json file to my acount in Datahub.io with `ckanclient`,
and I got this error:

```
ckanclient.CkanApiError: Got redirected to another URL, which does not work with POSTS. Redirection: http://thedatahub.org/api/storage/auth/form/2013-07-26T022918/my.json -> http://datahub.io/user/login?came_from=http://datahub.io/api/storage/auth/form/2013-07-26T022918/my.json
```

The code I use is this (This is the same code as in their API)

```
import ckanclient 

ckan = ckanclient.CkanClient(api_key='8a482c44-ef3d-4337-88c6-dca16fd6b3f3',)
ckan.upload_file('my.json')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ckanclient` is deprecated I believe.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are getting an access denied which is leading to a redirect to the login page:

```
.../user/login?came_from=http://datahub.io/api/storage/auth/form/2013-07-26T022918/my.json
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Not sure why that is happening - try visiting the relevant urls in your browser (whilst logged in obviously). Once that works you know it is something with the api key (and I hope that is not your *real* API Key you've pasted here ;-) ...)